# Multiple SQL import files in Spring Boot

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

Going by the [Spring Boot reference manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-hibernate), there are a couple of ways in which we can import data on startup of an application. Combined with an in-memory database, this is rather handy for testing.

The options are to create a file called `import.sql`, which will be picked up by Hibernate, or to create a file called `data.sql`, which will be picked up by Spring JDBC. Both of these work fine for me.

However, I like to break up my projects a bit, so I currently have a core domain model, where there are some handy imports to configure core data such as some users, which is used everywhere. I also have function-specific projects where it is useful to re-use that same import of base data, but also import some additional data which is specific to that function.

This is where things are not working so well.

I found [an answer to a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4047908/395821), where Pascal Thivent mentioned that the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files` property could be used to define a list of files, as of Hibernate 3.6.0.Beta1. Given that my project is importing 4.3.1.Final, I thought that perhaps this would be available.

So I tried adding the following to my Spring Boot `application.properties`:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files=/another-import.sql
```

and:

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files=/another-import.sql
```

Unfortunately, neither of these would cause the import to run.

So I'm wondering whether I just made a mess of the properties above (quite likely). Or is there something else that I need to do?

Note that as a workaround, I spotted that Spring JDBC seems to run `data.sql` after Hibernate runs `import.sql`. So as long as I don't need more than two imports, I'm able to use `import.sql` for the base data and then put project-specific imports in `data.sql`. I can get by with this, but it's not really a solution.

Comment: are you defining your own jpaProperties and entityManagerFactory beans, or using the default magic?

Comment: It's all just default magic. :)

Comment: use `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files`. See [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) for a list of properties. If you want multiple resources just use a common separated list for `spring.datasource.data` and/or `spring.datasource.schema` (which default to `data` and `schema` respectively. Or you can come up with a naming convention and put the expression in there `spring.datasource.data=classpath:/META-INF/sql/init-*.sql` for instance.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If you really want to use the hibernate property prefix it with `spring.jpa.properties.` as those are added as is as properties to the `EntityManagerFactory`. See [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html#howto-configure-jpa-properties) in the Spring Boot reference guide.

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files=file1.sql,file2.sql
```

However you can also use the `spring.datasource.data` and `spring.datasource.schema` properties to your advantage. They default to respectively `data` and `schema`. As you can see in the [DataSourceInitializer](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/112214a307dcacfe3b863c06acaa9e89fe015db5/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceInitializer.java) class. You can also set them and they take a comma separated list of resources.

```
spring.datasource.data=classpath:/data-domain.sql,file:/c:/sql/data-reference.sql,data-complex.sql
```

It gets even better because the resource loading also allows loading resources with [ant-style patterns](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-app-ctx-ant-patterns-in-paths).

```
spring.datasource.data=/META-INF/sql/init-*.sql
spring.datasource.schema=/META-INF/sql/schema-*.sql
```

Comment: That's the one ... a typo in my properties file. I think I made the same mistake before, because there are some `spring.jpa.hibernate` properties in my configs, so I just followed the same pattern.

Comment: I had to prefix the lines with "classpath*:/META-INF/..." (classpath with asterisk), to read files from other Maven modules. Nice answer, thanks!

Comment: Ditto w/ the `classpath*:` being needed even just for local packaged files.  I wanted to separate my stuff out more and use Flyways like conventions, so I have `spring.datasource.data=classpath*:db/data/V*.sql`

Comment: UPDATE: `spring.datasource.data` is no longer available starting from Spring Boot 2.5.0, you can use `spring.sql.init.data-locations` instead