# How to load data with data.sql using JHipster and Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

I have a Jhipster monolithic application. I removed Liquibase and I want to use data.sql file to insert initial data. I created a data.sql and data-h2.sql which contain insert scripts. They are located under `src/main/resources`. But none of the data seems to be inserted.

How can I use data.sql to insert data during startup, without using Liquibase?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24508223/multiple-sql-import-files-in-spring-boot

Comment: Well, that isn't exactly the answer to my question. I want to initialize my database using Spring (`https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc`).

By the way, the author references `DataSourceInitializer` class which helped me find out my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Commenting `spring.datasource.type` property and adding `spring.jpa.hibernate.create-drop` property helped resolve this issue. I think some jhipster configuration overrides default spring-boot configuration.

Here is how I come up with this solution:

While debugging `DataSourceInitializedPublisher.publishEventIfRequired`, I saw that following line returned a `null` reference:

```
private void publishEventIfRequired(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    DataSource dataSource = findDataSource(entityManagerFactory);
    ...
}
```

I commented `spring.datasource.type` property in `application-dev.yml`. In this way, spring switched to tomcat connection pool automatically.

Then, I found out that `DataSourceInitializedPublisher.isInitializingDatabase` required `spring.jpa.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` property to be defined in configuration:

```
private boolean isInitializingDatabase(DataSource dataSource) {
    ...
    if (hibernate.containsKey("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto")) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

After adding the missing property, spring-boot started to execute `data.sql` file.

**Update**

For those who want to execute a platform specific `data.sql` file, such as `data-h2.sql`, you should also add following property:

```
spring.datasource.platform=h2
```

**Update**

For those who need to convert default Jhipster data stored in csv files into sql format, you may refer to following gist:

https://gist.github.com/hkarakose/cf7f1b5b241dad611ba01c0211f42108