# JHipster 5 and Spring Boot does not load data.sql on startup

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jhipster, h2

I generated a Microservice Application with JHipster 5.0.1 (based on Spring Boot 2). I am using memory based persistence H2 in dev mode. Have not changed the generated code and configuration in any way.
Spring Boot is supposed to load and execute the src/main/resources/data.sql file automatically while starting. This does not work however, the files are not executed.

I am aware of what needs to be configured in Spring Boot to execute data.sql (and schema.sql) files. I have disabled auto-ddl:

```
spring.application.jpa.hibernate.auto-ddl=none
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45266698/how-to-load-data-with-data-sql-using-jhipster-and-spring-boot) describes the same issue, but the actions taken there do not work.

Comment: JHipster uses Liquibase, any reason why you don't enclose your data.sql into a changelog ?

Comment: I have not used Liquibase before and am just using the default configuration for it. Does this mean that all DB imports etc shall be handled by Liquibase?

Comment: Yes to get full control, Liquibase keeps track of MD5 checksums of all changelogs to detect unmanaged changes. See Liquibase doc and src/main/resources/config/liquibase in your project generated by JHipster