# Multiple SQL import files in Spring Boot - no wildcards in classpath resource possible

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

As I can't comment on [M.Deinums answer in another post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24508223/multiple-sql-import-files-in-spring-boot/24509981#24509981), I have to open a complete new question:

I just noticed that

```
spring.datasource.data=file:/somepath/to/somewhere/init-*.sql
```

works, but not

```
spring.datasource.data=classpath:/init-*.sql
```

Wonder why. Didn't find any clue in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

As it is difficult to find special characters with the current search machines,
it took a while to finding the solution:

> A ResourcePatternResolver implementation that is able to resolve a
>   specified resource location path into one or more matching Resources.
>   The source path may be a simple path which has a one-to-one mapping to
>   a target Resource, or alternatively may contain the special
>   "classpath*:" prefix and/or internal Ant-style regular expressions
>   (matched using Spring's AntPathMatcher utility). Both of the latter
>   are effectively wildcards.

taken from: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.html

So, the solution is (mind the asterisk):

```
spring.datasource.data=classpath:/data.sql,classpath*:/init-*.sql
```