# Could not found the UserRepository Bean when I exclude DataSourceAutoConfiguration class from the autoconfiguration in spring boot JPA

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Initially, I got below error when I was trying to load multiple .sql files to run at the time of application start.

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unable to load resources from db/scripts/*.sql

And to resolve this issue I excluded the DataSourceAutoconfiguration.class like below:
@SpringBootApplication(Exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class}

but not now for all the @Repository interfaces beans are not created.

Field userRepository in com.atlokal.user.mgmt.user.dao.UserDaoImpl required a bean of type 'com.atlokal.user.mgmt.user.dao.UserRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.atlokal.user.mgmt.user.dao.UserRepository' in your configuration.

could you please help me out to solve this issue ?

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class AtlokalUserMgmtApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AtlokalUserMgmtApplication.class, args);
    }

}

application.properties

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.sql.init.data-locations=db/scripts/*.sql
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=false

UserDaoImpl.java
@Component
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;
    @Override
    public UserEntity createUser(UserDto userDto) {
        return userRepository.save(modelMapper.map(userDto,UserEntity.class));
    }
}

UserRepository.java
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserEntity, Long> {
}
```

Comment: Can i know, why are you excluding the datasource auto configuration ?

Comment: I have a requirement to execute multiple .sql files at the time of application startup, after adding this spring.sql.init.data-locations=db/scripts/*.sql in the property file I got a BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' issue to resolve this issue I am trying to exclude it

Comment: I think in this case is better to  use something like  liquibase or flyway for database scripts as version of control and init scripts

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, if it didn't work I will try to use the liquibase files only

Comment: and also about your topic/problem i think this is relevant [question/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24508223/multiple-sql-import-files-in-spring-boot)

Comment: Actually no, because I would like try with .sql files without using liquibase files

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, the files were not found.
Please use classpath: to specify that the sql files need to be picked up from resources.

```
spring.sql.init.data-locations=classpath:db/scripts/*.sql
```

Comment: I tried it already,the application is running successfully but the table wasn't created which means the .sql file is not executed I guess

Comment: Weird, I did try the same and it did work for me. Could you please share the version of spring boot that you are running? Also what db are you using?

Comment: I am using the 3.1.2 spring boot version with PostgreSQL. and this is the query I added in .sql file CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USER_MODEL(ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    FIRST_NAME CHAR(120) NOT NULL,
    LAST_NAME CHAR(50),
    GENDER CHAR,
    USER_EMAIL VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    USER_MOBILE_NUMBER VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PASSWORD VARCHAR(28) NOT NULL,
    BIRTH_DATE DATE,
    UNIQUE(USER_EMAIL, USER_MOBILE_NUMBER)
);

Comment: Tried the same with the given sql file and version on Postgres. Works good for me. Are your sql files where you say they are?

Comment: under resource folder db/migration/  it is not at picking up the file for execution

Comment: path you have provided is db/scripts in the properties, change that to db/migration.